# Debugging jest mocks

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've got a library that's giving me some trouble in my jest tests.

This library is included throughout my project, and it has an `annoyingFunction` that has a `console.error` in it. So, whenever I run a test, I naturally get unwanted `console.error` messages all over the place.

I don't want to mock out the whole library, just the `annoyingFunction`, so I put this in my setup file:

```
jest.mock('myLibrary', () => ({
   ...jest.requireActual('myLibrary'),
   annoyingFunction: jest.fn(),
}));
```

This is being run, however, the original `annoyingFunction` is still being called, polluting my tests with `console.error` calls.

If I console log my mock, I clearly see `annoyingFunction: [Function: mockConstructor]`, so the mock is working, but for some reason, the original function from the library is still being called.

What am I missing here? Is there something wrong with my initial setup of the mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a couple of things wrong, but my guess is that `annoyingFunction` is called internally within the library.  Consider the following example, which doesn't do what you might expect it to:

**foo.js**

```
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function subtract(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

function multiply(a, b) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    total = add(total, a);
  }
  return total;
}

export {
  add,
  subtract,
  multiply
};
```

**foo_test.js**

```
import * as Operations from "./foo.js";

jest.mock("./foo.js", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("./foo.js"),
  add: () => -999,
}));

describe("all the things", () => {
  // Here, the mock does what you would expect, because you're calling the
  // exported function "add."
  it("can add", () => {
    expect(Operations.add(1, 2)).toEqual(-999);
  });
  it("can subtract", () => {
    expect(Operations.subtract(1, 2)).toEqual(-1);
  });
  // Here, the mock doesn't do what you would expect. because unbeknownst to
  // you, `multiply` calls `add` _within_ the module code.  The mock has no
  // effect in this case.
  it("can multiply", () => {
    expect(Operations.multiply(1, 2)).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

I'm not really sure what you can do about this, except to mock exported methods of the library until you can control the result.

Or...you could `jest.spyOn` `console.error` for whichever test is giving you a problem, and [reset the spy afterward](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

```
const consoleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(console, "error");
//...do your test...
consoleErrorSpy.mockRestore();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're right, this is exactly what is happening. I guess I erroneously thought that when I mocked out the function, it would replace all calls of the function, including the ones internal to the library itself.

Comment: The issue with mocking out the console error is that `annoyingFunction` is actually run in virtually every test in a suite of thousands. So I wouldn't want to have to mock it out for each individual test. I considered mocking it globally, since I'm not sure I ever want console.error in my test suite, but was hesitant to do so since I'm unsure what the unintended side effects would be

Comment: Yes, I think it might be hard to prove you haven't clobbered a legit call to `console.error`.  Maybe time to fork the library!