# How to mock a named export on which another named export in a same file depends

Tags: javascript, jestjs, mocking, es6-modules

Given a JS file like this:

```js
export const uid = () => Math.random().toString();
export const doubleUid = () => [uid(),uid()].join('_');
```

How can you use Jest to mock `uid` as `() => 'foo'` such that the result of `doubleUid()` is `foo_foo`? Is it possible to do so without modifying the file above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock functions in the same module using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45111198/how-to-mock-functions-in-the-same-module-using-jest)

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/70066090/3001761, which is to say: don't.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify that I'm asking how to do it 'without modifying the file' . The referenced issue doesn't answer that – all of the suggestions either involve modifying the file to test OR rely on the tested code already be deterministic.

Comment: You already _shouldn't_, but without modifying the file you _can't_.

Comment: Update – one of the comments does mention babel-rewire-plugin – which could solve this for some people depending on their stack https://stackoverflow.com/a/52725067/3758164

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this using mocks.

You have to mock each exported function separately. Mocking the exported version of the first function doesn't change the original implementation of the second exported function.

See this answer I gave to a related sort of question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72192912/3084820